# JsonSlurper parsing String containing Json into unexpected format

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

From a separate system I get a String parameter "messageJson" whose content is in the form:

```
{"agent1":"smith","agent2":"brown","agent3":{"agent3_1":"jones","agent3_2":"johnson"}}
```

To use it in my program I parse it with JsonSlurper.

```
def myJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageJson)
```

But the resulting Json has the form:

```
[agent1:smith, agent2:brown, agent3:[agent3_1:jones, agent3_2:johnson]]
```

Note the square brackets and the lack of double quotes. How can I parse messageJson so that the original structure is kept?

Comment: This is no JSON - its the .toString() from Groovy; JsonSlurper reads the JSON and turns it into Map:s.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks, I misunderstood JsonSlurper. I've tried it now with JsonOutput.toJson, but the result is {\"agent1\":\"smith\",\"agent2":\"brown\", ... and so on. How can I get the original format in a format that I can work with? I need to be able to add and remove keys and afterwards send the Json along to another system in the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the hint by cfrick, I was able to find a solution. In case anyone else has a similar problem, all I needed to do was using JsonOutput in the end to convert the map back to a Json

I.E. :

```
def myJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageJson)
myJson << [agent4:"jane"]
def backToJson = JsonOutput.toJson(myJson)
```